# Whatsapp deleting contacts permanently

Tags: gmail

I've tried every way. Deleted from Main phone book of contacts. Deleted all chat. Blocked but I want to delete them FOREVER to tidy up my whatsapp list... 
PLEASE anyone help?  I would be eternally grateful..   :-)

Answer (score 1):

Delete the contacts from your Google account and any other local accounts.

Then go into the contacts tab and click the menu button followed by the refresh button.

This information is sourced from [here.](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20970403)

Alternatively go into WhatsApp > Settings > Contacts. Toggle the Show All Contacts field which I believe also refresh the contact list. After toggling, it will refresh (which may take some time) at which point you can return to the original setting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work, but just see if your contacts are synced with google account. If so, just try deleting them from google account.

Comment: that sounds like it might be happening. how do I delete them from google when I never added them and don't know the people who are blocked?